# How do I change the "selected" attribute on an option tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a web form for an online order. I want to make the select box default to the current month using javaScript but it doesn't seem to be working for me and I'm not sure why. I am new to javascript but I thought I figured this out. Am I missing something or mis-interpreting something?
Here is the HTML:

```
<label for="orderMonth">Month</label>
            <select name="month" id="orderMonth" onchange="setselect()">
                <option value="01" id="m0">January</option>
                <option value="02" id="m1">February</option>
                <option value="03" id="m2">March</option>
                <option value="04" id="m3">Aprl</option>
                <option value="05" id="m4">May</option>
                <option value="06" id="m5">June</option>
                <option value="07" id="m6">July</option>
                <option value="08" id="m7">August</option>
                <option value="09" id="m8">September</option>
                <option value="10" id="m9">October</option>
                <option value="11" id="m10">November</option>
                <option value="12" id="m11">December</option>
            </select>
```

And here is the script the first way I tried it:

```
<script>
        var month = getMonth();
        var opt = document.getElementById("m"+month);
        opt.setAttribute("selected");
    </script>
```

and the second way I tried it:

```
<script>
        var month = getMonth();
        if (month == 0) {
            document.getElementById("m0").selected = true;}
        else if (month == 1) {
            document.getElementById("m1").selected = true;}
        else if (month == 2) {
            document.getElementById("m2").selected = true;}
        else if (month == 3) {
            document.getElementById("m3").selected = true;}
        else if (month == 4) {
            document.getElementById("m4").selected = true;}
        else if (month == 5) {
            document.getElementById("m5").selected = true;}
        else if (month == 6) {
            document.getElementById("m6").selected = true;}
        else if (month == 7) {
            document.getElementById("m7").selected = true;}
        else if (month == 8) {
            document.getElementById("m8").selected = true;}
        else if (month == 9) {
            document.getElementById("m9").selected = true;}
        else if (month == 10) {
            document.getElementById("m10").selected = true;}
        else if(month == 11) {
            document.getElementById("m11").selected = true;}
    </script>
```

Thoughts anyone?

Comment: I think the setting is selected instead of true.

Comment: @nocturns2—no, it's not.

Comment: @RobG  you're right. My brainfart, comfused it with the <option> html setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a new Date obj to take the month.Look the code below:

```js
var today=new Date();
var month = today.getMonth();
        if (month == 0) {
            document.getElementById("m0").selected = true;}
        else if (month == 1) {
            document.getElementById("m1").selected = true;}
        else if (month == 2) {
            document.getElementById("m2").selected = true;}
        else if (month == 3) {
            document.getElementById("m3").selected = true;}
        else if (month == 4) {
            document.getElementById("m4").selected = true;}
        else if (month == 5) {
            document.getElementById("m5").selected = true;}
        else if (month == 6) {
            document.getElementById("m6").selected = true;}
        else if (month == 7) {
            document.getElementById("m7").selected = true;}
        else if (month == 8) {
            document.getElementById("m8").selected = true;}
        else if (month == 9) {
            document.getElementById("m9").selected = true;}
        else if (month == 10) {
            document.getElementById("m10").selected = true;}
        else if(month == 11) {
            document.getElementById("m11").selected = true;}
```

Comment: I corrected the js and changed the 'true' to "selected". Though it still isn't having the effect I'm looking for. The page still renders with January as the default option when it should be June if the code worked. I currently have this code in my header with the script tags. Is there something else I'm missing here?

Comment: The code works fine to me.I don't have any errors and the month is June.Check the script to be at the bottom of the body element.

Comment: Ah, that was it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works if you change:

```
var month = getMonth();
```

to

```
var month = new Date().getMonth();
```

However, since the month number matches the option index, you can simply set the select's *selectedIndex* to the month number:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('orderMonth').selectedIndex = new Date().getMonth();
}
```

```html
<label for="orderMonth">Month</label>
<select name="month" id="orderMonth" onchange="setselect()">
  <option value="01" id="m0">January</option>
  <option value="02" id="m1">February</option>
  <option value="03" id="m2">March</option>
  <option value="04" id="m3">Aprl</option>
  <option value="05" id="m4">May</option>
  <option value="06" id="m5">June</option>
  <option value="07" id="m6">July</option>
  <option value="08" id="m7">August</option>
  <option value="09" id="m8">September</option>
  <option value="10" id="m9">October</option>
  <option value="11" id="m10">November</option>
  <option value="12" id="m11">December</option>
</select>
```

You could also do:

```
document.getElementById('orderMonth').options[new Date().getMonth()].selected = true;
```